# Is there an equivalent flag as '-y' for choosing options in bash?

Tags: bash, flags

I'm launching the script to install `Rust` on my macOs. The command line is the following:

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

What I get is (I cropped it):

```
Welcome to Rust!

This will download and install the official compiler for the Rust programming 
language, and its package manager, Cargo.

Current installation options:

   default host triple: x86_64-apple-darwin
     default toolchain: stable
  modify PATH variable: yes

1) Proceed with installation (default)
2) Customize installation
3) Cancel installation
>
```

I have to choose an option between 1, 2 and 3. But I would like to add a flag in the command line to always choose an option, say 2.
I'm thinking of something like:

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -2
```

in the same vein as `-y` to force "yes" to all questions. But none of this worked.

Is there a way to do so in `bash`?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```sh
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
```

[This](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/297#issuecomment-589989163) explains the command syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you first download the script using `wget` you can pass a single answer to it on standard input:

```
echo 2 | ./script.sh
```

Goods scripts have command line options to do that; you could try `./script.sh --help` to see if the option exists.

Bad scripts may actively clear out standard input before asking for a response, in which case you may have to use `expect` to automate the process.

Comment: The script doesn't read from stdin (it can't if it has to work as `... | sh`).

Comment: @melpomene If the script doesn't read from stdin, how do you explain it receiving input from the user?

Comment: @bishop I mean, you could just [look at the code](https://sh.rustup.rs/): `ignore "$_file" "$@" < /dev/tty` It reads from /dev/tty.

Comment: @melpomene Yuck.